# Corners Pieces of Tub Surround bowed out

Tags: bathtub

Just trying to glue up my tub surround this weekend. I have ran into a snaggle that I cannot think or find an answer to. The problem is when I put my corner piece on ( 5 piece surround), the middle side of the corner bows out. So if I push the top into the wall, and the bottom into the tub corner, the middle bows out.

[image]

It seems that the bottom goes over the lip of the tub (pulling the corner away from the wall) and the top of the wall seems to lean inwards towards the tub. Which leaves me with a middle section that I cannot see sticking to the wall if I glue it where you see it. Obviously I don't want a huge caulking line overtop of the seam inside the tub.

I am not sure if the fact that the tub corner is also quite far from our wall contributes as well.

[image]

Thats me pointing to the bottom of the tub where the bow out seems to be happening above. Anybody have any advice? Duct tape thick on the inside?? I am at a loss trying to figure something! Thanks for reading.

Comment: I once bought a 5 piece surround, got it home, unpacked it, packed it back up, took it back to the store, returned it, and paid twice as much for a 3-piece surround. It was just too thin/cheaply made to be reasonable. This may or may not apply to your surround.

Comment: Haha. We ended up gluing it in. Still have the huge gaps that we will try to figure out something to fix. Probably fill in the gaps between the layers with silicone, holding it in place with spring shower curtain rods till it dries. We live in a trailer, and are only replacing the surround to make sure the wall behind wasn't rotting. But I like your thought.